# Tag synonymy between resample and resampling?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [resample](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resample) and a [resampling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resampling) which generally seem to be applied in the same context. Should one be made synonym of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with PolyGeo that [resampling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resampling) should be the master. IMO, when in doubt, check [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resampling) (or another relevant SE site, e.g. [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resampling) in this case) to see if it has an equivalent tag, or Wikipedia's [disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resample) / [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Resample&redirect=no) pages. Failing that, there is always [Google Fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=resample&word2=resampling) :)

See also [kriging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kriging), [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing), [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling), etc.

Comment: Interesting (valid) reasoning. I was approaching as tag the 'thing' not the 'act of thing' and I guess we saw different examples first when looking. So I guess we need to fix [tag:convert], [tag:export], [tag:import], etc. Or maybe we just forget standardizing and worrying about changing tags we have, and if there's a duplicate like there was with resample/georeference just go with majority use (on here) rules in determining master. As whuber mentioned in the first place. :)

Comment: I generally equate tags with topics, so instead of `convert` I would probably have `conversion` (which is already a synonym). Not sure about `export` and `import`, but deferring to StackOverflow and Wikipedia, they are both in that form, so I guess  I'm fine with them. I agree though it's probably not worth fretting over them too much and just deal with them on a case by case basis.

Comment: So, since @whuber already did it can it be undone and reversed? Does it matter? I'm ok with either way really.

Comment: @ChrisW We have a swap button to reverse master and synonym so with consensus which I think we seem already near it will be very easy to implement. Thanks for the time you are spending on helping to streamline our tags.

Answer (score 1):

[resampling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resampling) should be made a synonym of [resample](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resample). In my opinion this would be more consistent for tags (verb instead of the participle). I'm proposing a Wiki for resample to address the lack and a modification of resampling just in case.

Comment: Because you have put such effort into the tag wikis, I implemented your proposal (despite that [tag:resampling] was twice as popular as [tag:resample]).

Comment: @whuber Thanks. When I started writing the answer and up to that point I actually had it the other way for just that reason (well, that and ing already had a Wiki). But then I started thinking about it and it seemed verb instead of participle would be cleaner as a 'standard'. Which I thought several tags were following, but I've just noticed [tag:georeference] and [tag:georeferencing] just to disprove me. I wonder if that should be in the guidelines for tags or if I'm just splitting hairs. :)

Comment: I'm not sure where/when the "ing" convention arose but it is what I have been following.  I think standardizing on the site preference (whichever that is) should be [documented](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).  I certainly agree that the two terms are synonyms.